# DOMPDF abrir conteúdo Bootstrap deitado e reconhecer CSS

Tags: php, dompdf

Estou usando o DOMPDF com o conteúdo com Bootstrap. Para isso, fiz dessa forma:

```
 <?php
    ...
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    use Dompdf\Options;
    require_once("dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
    $options = new Options();
    $options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF($options);
    $dompdf->load_html('
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <title>Carteira Digital</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                             <div class="row" style="background-color: #0C4160; border-bottom: 10px #FEC236 solid;">
                                 Conteúdo
                             </div>
                       </div>
            </div>
');
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();
```

O problema é que o conteúdo continua saindo em pé e o `background-color: #0C4160;` não está sendo reconhecido.

Comment: Antes de instanciar `DOMPDF` coloque `$options->set('defaultPaperOrientation' , 'landscape');` e  `$options->set('defaultPaperSize' , 'A4');`. As definições do papel devem ser feitas antes de carregar o conteúdo.